# (Sendgrid v3 API) Is there something wrong in my API command (my emails are ending up in spam)?

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

It has been just 1½ weeks since I setup my free email API account on Sendgrid, & I have sent only ~12 emails ever since (to my family members for testing purposes). I have a fully verified single sender for my personal email address `xxxxxxxx@gmail.com` and I am using the same to send the email through API.

Here's the cURL API I built, to send an email to 4 addresses using a dynamic template -

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <MY_API_KEY>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [{"email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}],
      "dynamic_template_data": {"first_name": "xxxxxxxx","date": "9th Nov. 2021","city": "Mumbai"}
    },
    {
      "to": [{"email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}],
      "dynamic_template_data": {"first_name": "xxxxxxxx","date": "27th Oct. 2021","city": "Mumbai"}
    },
    {
      "to": [{"email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}],
      "dynamic_template_data": {"first_name": "xxxxxxxx","date": "9th Jun. 2021","city": "Mumbai"}
    },
    {
      "to": [{"email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}],
      "dynamic_template_data": {"first_name": "xxxxxxxx","date": "21st Oct. 2021","city": "Mumbai"}
    }
  ],
  "from": {"email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "name":"xxxxxxxx"},
  "template_id" : "<MY_TEMPLATE_ID>"
}'
```

The email is sent perfectly to all the four recipients, except it ends up in spam for all four of them. Since my account is pretty much new, and I have barely sent any emails (and for the ones I sent, no one marked them as spam/etc.), I wonder what's causing my sent emails to end up in Spam... Is there something wrong in the API I built? Is sending to multiple people causing this?

Please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

It appears that you have verified a Gmail address as a single sender and you are sending emails to other Gmail addresses.

Verifying as single sender lets SendGrid know that you own the email address, but it does not help to prove that to other inboxes. In this case, you are sending from a Gmail address to a Gmail address, and such Gmail knows 100% that Gmail did not send the email in the first place. Since Gmail did not send the email from the Gmail address, it seems to Gmail that it is spam, regardless of the content.

Using [Single Sender Verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) is good for testing your code, but it is [not recommended for production use](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity#single-sender-verification). To give yourself a better chance of not ending up in spam inboxes we recommend [Domain Authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication). [Domain Authentication also sets up SPF and DKIM](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication#key-terminology), and can set you on the path to DMARC, all of which give your email address sender better reputation.

Comment: *"Since Gmail did not send the email from the Gmail address, it seems to Gmail that it is spam."* > Ah, I guess you are right on this  What if I still want to send emails with my @gmail.com address? Will I need to authenticate the **gmail.com** domain? If so, how would I do the same? TBH I am a bit confused, as I am unable to find the procedure for authenticating gmail domain  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can't authenticate the gmail domain because you don't own it. If you could do that, you could spoof any gmail address and that would not be good! I would recommend getting your own domain and sending from that instead.

Comment: Alright! So summarizing, I cannot send emails to my recipients if I use an email address with `@gmail.com`/`@live.com`/etc. as the domain - It must be a domain I personally own. If I still try to send with a free domain (gmail.com/live.com), all my recipients who happen to have the same domain in their addresses will not be able to receive the email, as it would be marked 'spam', because it was not sent from their platform. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: For the best results for landing in an inbox you should send from a domain you own and can authenticate through the domain authentication process. If you send on behalf of a gmail/live.com email then you won’t have the backing of SPF or DKIM, so even inboxes that aren’t the same domain will find the emails suspicious and likely send them to spam. Nothing is exact in the world of email though, so you could send from a gmail domain and it not go to spam and until you build up a reputation your new domain may also go to spam. What I’ve described gives you the best chance of landing in the inbox.